# Accessing outer scope from jQuery.each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to iterate over all elements of "shift" and update an outer array called new_requests, how do i do this ?, currently i get an undefined error on the line thats supposed to update the array. thanks.

```
$scope.save = function(){

                var new_requests = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];

                $("shift").each(function(){

                     var day = $("this").attr("day");
                     var shift = $("this").attr("shift");
                     var status =  $("this").attr("status");
                     new_requests[day][shift]=status;

                })
                console.log(new_requests);
            }
```

Comment: what is the output of `day` and `shifts` in the loop?

Comment: I doubt that there is an HTML tag "shift". Do you mean an ID ($("#shift")) or class($(".shift"))?

Comment: what is `shift`? `this` is not a string. Why do you even need to use jQuery for this and not do it with angular? Provide sample html for issues like these

Comment: I Solved my problem. however how would you do this in angular ? i have a table with these <shift></shift> elements in the <td></td>. i need to collect all the data from these elements and put into an array. the shift tag is a custom tag of mine. i used it inside an Angular Directive template because when angular computes the template it discards the directive tag itself, and i wanted that tag to stick data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `shift` is a collection of elements with `day`, `shift` and `status` attributes, use:

```
$.each($(shift), function() {
     var day = $(this).attr("day");
     var shift = $(this).attr("shift");
     var status =  $(this).attr("status");
     new_requests[day][shift]=status;
     });
```

Note `$(shift)` instead of `$("shift")` and `$(this)` instead of `$("this")`.

Comment: Thanks!. such a newbie i am ;). removing the quotation marks around the "this" solved the problem. guess there was never a problem accessing the outer variable "new_requests".